# how to show status bar in ribbon window wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, statusbar

I would like to use the ribbon bar like MS Office 2007 (and greater) in my own applications. Could anyone please provide me with links or references about how I can do this?

**EDIT:**
Actually I am using Microsoft's Ribbon Control Library but could not found way to add status bar like MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe give [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ribboncontrol.aspx) a shot?

**EDIT:** Actually, apparently Microsoft [have released their own](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx).

Comment: Actually I am using Microsoft's Ribbon Control Library but could not found way to add status bar like MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the way to display `StatusBar` in a good way,

I hope it helps some else.. ..

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top">
          <ribbon:RibbonTab Label="Banking">
             <ribbon:RibbonGroup>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Cut"/>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Copy"/>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Paste"/>
             </ribbon:RibbonGroup>

             <ribbon:RibbonGroup>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.AddNew"/>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Clear" />
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Delete"/>
             </ribbon:RibbonGroup>

            <ribbon:RibbonGroup>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.DownloadStatements"/>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.DownloadCreditCards"/>
                  <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="me:AppCommands.Transfer"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
         </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>

    <StatusBar x:Name="StatusBar"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <StatusBarItem Margin="0,-3,0,-2" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="statusBarText">www.247moneymakingschemes.blogspot.com</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
                <ProgressBar Width="80"
                             Height="18"
                             Value="30" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="3">
                <TextBlock>Go!</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>

       <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Put your main content/items control here as last child in dock panel" />
</DockPanel>
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has made their ribbon control officially available for WPF. Its free, and its the real deal, strait from the horses mouth. You can read about it [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx), and download it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx).